# Rearranging a Dataframe into 1 column and 1 index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have the following dataframe and I want to create a new dataframe with one column being unique strikes (no repetition) and one index (TimeUntilExpiration-unique values) with the Mid values being the values that corresponds to a unique combination of TimeUntilExpiration and Strike.

```
 TimeUntilExpiration  Strike    Mid

0               0.010959   22.75  2.325
1               0.010959   23.00  2.200
2               0.010959   23.25  2.100
3               0.010959   23.50  1.975
4               0.010959   23.75  1.875
..                   ...     ...    ...
307             2.043836   25.00  1.455
308             2.043836   26.00  1.015
309             2.043836   27.00  2.795
310             2.043836   28.00  0.395
311             2.043836   29.00  0.205
```

Tried so many ways and mapping but nothing seemed to work. Appreciate any help:)

Comment: You can modify the data because your question is not readable.

Comment: in your example data it looks like the Strikes are already unique? Is this the final output you're trying to make? If so can you paste your input?

Comment: I modified the data apologies. As for the strikes, they look unique because the data is huge and this is only a small representation.  I had a huge dataset, created this dataframe based on 3 columns, and now I want to adjust this dataframe and create a new one based on one unique column (Strikes), one unique index(TimeUntilExpiration) and the corresponding 'Mid' values for every unique strike and TimeUntilExpiraton

Comment: Do you want to [pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47152691/15239951) your dataframe?

Comment: You didn't update your example, those are still unique values :)

Comment: Thanks everyone. it was just a pivot table:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to [pivot your dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47152691/15239951)?

```
>>> df.pivot_table('Mid', 'TimeUntilExpiration', 'Strike')

Strike               22.75  23.00  23.25  23.50  23.75  25.00  26.00  27.00  28.00  29.00
TimeUntilExpiration                                                                      
0.010959             2.325    2.2    2.1  1.975  1.875    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2.043836               NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  1.455  1.015  2.795  0.395  0.205
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=["TimeUntilExpiration",'Strike'], value_vars=["Mid"], value_name='Mid values').drop('variable', axis=1)
```

Result:

| index | TimeUntilExpiration | Strike | Mid values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.010959 | 22.75 | 2.325 |
| 1 | 0.010959 | 23.0 | 2.2 |
| 2 | 0.010959 | 23.25 | 2.1 |
| 3 | 0.010959 | 23.5 | 1.975 |
| 4 | 0.010959 | 23.75 | 1.875 |
| 5 | 2.043836 | 25.0 | 1.455 |
| 6 | 2.043836 | 26.0 | 1.015 |
| 7 | 2.043836 | 27.0 | 2.795 |
| 8 | 2.043836 | 28.0 | 0.395 |
| 9 | 2.043836 | 29.0 | 0.205 |